# Cómo guardar otro valor que no sea el ID de un select dinámico?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de guardar los valores de un select dinámico en una tabla de la base de datos. Esto funciona pero el problema es que los valores guardados son los ID's y no los nombres (por ejemplo) que necesito.

Si bien el código es bastante sencillo, no consigo aún resolver esto.

El proyecto se divide como sigue:

index.php
conexion.php
marcas.php
modelos.php
color.php

```
**Este es el js que uso**

    <script type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function(){
    $("#marcas").load("php/marcas.php");

    $("#marcas").change(function(){
      var id = $("#marcas").val();
      $.get("php/modelos.php",{param_id:id})
        .done(function(data){
        $("#modelos").html(data);
      })
    })

    $("#modelos").change(function(){
      var id = $("#modelos").val();
      $.get("php/color.php",{param_id:id})
        .done(function(data){
        $("#color").html(data);
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

Esto es marcas.php

```
<?php 
require "conexion.php";
echo '<option value="">Selecciona</option>';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM marca");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo '<option value="'.$row['idmarca'].'">'.$row['marca'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

Esto es modelos.php

```
<?php 
require "conexion.php";
echo '<option value="">Selecciona</option>';
$idmarca = $_GET['param_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM modelo WHERE idmarca = $idmarca");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<option value="'.$row['idmodelo'].'">'.$row['modelo'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

Esto es color.php

```
<?php 
require "conexion.php";
echo '<option value="">Selecciona</option>';
$idmodelo = $_GET['param_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM color WHERE idmodelo = $idmodelo");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<option value="'.$row['idcolor'].'">'.$row['color'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

Y lo que uso para guardar los valores en la tabla es esto

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

$marcas = $_POST['marcas'];
$modelos = $_POST['modelos'];
$color = $_POST['color'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO reservas (marca, modelo, color)
VALUES ('$marcas', '$modelos', '$color')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Espero haberme explicado correctamente y que puedan darme una mano para resolver.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: en donde de todo este codigo tenes problemas?

Comment: Gracias por contestar. En el codigo precisamente no es el problema. El problema es que esto guarda el ID de los selects pero lo que necesito es guardar por ejemplo la marca en lugar del id de la marca, el modelo en lugar del id del modelo

Comment: En donde pasa eso? no es incorrecto guardar en la db los codigos de las tablas relacionados. que pasa si mañana una marca cambia de nombre?

Comment: La verdad al menos en este proyecto no está contemplada la idea de solo cambiar una marca de nombre como comentas, sino agregar una nueva desde 0 con sus nuevos valores y demás

Comment: CarlosPortillo, en serio lo digo, créeme que eso de "no está contemplada la idea" es algo más que habitual y nuestro trabajo también consiste en prevenir defectos de forma que el cliente (o el jefe) no tenga contemplado en un principio. Lo más habitual es lo que te comenta @gbianchi, a menos que sepas que se necesita que el nombre, en caso de cambio, se **deba** guardar como era inicialmente. Guardar el id en vez del texto facilita las búsquedas y las relaciones entre tablas, evita errores tipográficos y permite a los frameworks desarrollar todo el potencial de las bases de datos relacionales.

Comment: Si aún así no deseas guardar los IDs sino los textos, lo que debes hacer es poner ese dato como `value` del `option`. Es decir : `echo '<option value="'.$row['modelo'].'">'.$row['modelo'].'</option>';`

Comment: si se necesitas guardar el nombre, la tabla que tiene esos nombres tambien debe tener fechas de validez (inicio, fin). Si esto no es un datawarehouse, no tiene sentido

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Creo que ya tengo como resolver según lo que comentan.

Comment: En Javascript, si tienes referencia del elemento actual, te puedes valer de `this` para obtener lo que necesitas del elemento y luego pasarlo al servidor vía Ajax. Por ejemplo, si en vez del `id` quieres el `value`, puedes recuperarlo con `this.value`. O sea, que puedes cambiar esto: `var id = $("#marcas").val();` por esto: `var id=this.value;` En ese caso `this` haría referencia al `select` actual que ha cambiado. No obstante, debes considerar lo que han comentado los compañeros sobre la conveniencia de usar identificadores numéricos en vez de texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para seleccionar el `id/value` de un select lo que tienes que usar es `val()` directamente sobre el `select`. En caso de que quieras obtener el texto incluido en la opción seleccionada lo que tienes que hacer es acceder al texto del `option:selected` en el `select`.

```js
function obtenerValor(){
  let value = $("#coches").val();
  return value;
}

function obtenerContenido(){
  let text = $("#coches option:selected").text();
  return text;
}

$("#coches").change(function(){
  console.log("Id o value de la opción seleccionada: "+obtenerValor());
  console.log("Texto de la opción seleccionada: "+obtenerContenido());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="coches">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Probaré con esto también!